# How can i use the same custom fonts for android as for ios using react native

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

I am working with the same code for both ios and android using react native. Now in my project I want to use custom fonts for both. I know how to apply custom fonts for ios but those same fonts how to apply for android also?

//New sample

> I added the custom font under
>   sample/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/gillsans-italic.ttf  I
>   applied this gillsans-italic.ttf  font in CustomFontTest component
>   like below

```
var CustomFontTest = React.createClass({
      render:function(){
         return (<View><Text style={styles.customFont}>CustomFont</Text></View>)
      }
})
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    customFont:{
        fontFamily:'gillsans-italic',
        fontSize:14,
        color:'#efefef'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your fonts under `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`.

They must be named according to the font family name. Here is what is supported:

{{fontName}}.otf
{{fontName}}_bold.otf
{{fontName}}_bold_italic.otf

You can replace .otf with .ttf. The `{{fontName}}` is the name you pass through to the `style` property of a component.

Comment: I did the same like what you are explaining but i am not getting custom font in android.I edit with new sample of code above

Comment: Your font family should still be "gillsans" and you should set the `fontStyle` to italic.

Comment: The font family itself italic ,same font family i applied to ios without setting any fontStyle property its applied.For android is it required again to apply fontStyle property

Comment: This works for me. If the font name is `Lato-Light.ttf` then the StyleSheet should be `fontFamily: "Lato-Light"` and you have to repackage the app with `react-native run-android`

Comment: This isn't documented very well at all at the moment. This answer works really well. The only thing I'd add is to remove "-" from filenames for android studio. For example, I changed `Lato-Light.ttf` to `LatoLight.ttf`