# custom font for both ios and Android in react native

Tags: android, ios, fonts, react-native

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34618578/1310740) to install custom in RN. 
It works in Android but not in ios.

When running on ios, is shows error with font not found.

How do I make it work for both ios and Android?

Comment: Did you cleaned and rebuild your app from xcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply create an 'assets' folder in the root of your project (or wherever you want), drop in your font files, and define it in your project's package.json.

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": ["assets"]
},
```

Then, run react-native link and besides linking 3rd party modules, it will now also link any fonts you put in there with the respective project files.

from 
[React Native: Things I wish I knew before starting out.](https://blog.jari.io/react-native/)

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: do we also have to use the same thing if we are using react native version 0.60