# React-native custom font file naming

Tags: android, react-native, fonts, styled-components

Is it possible to name the custom font files such that Android will automatically find the right one based on the style provided?

I am using custom font with styled components and this seems to work fine on iOS but not on Android:

```
font-family: 'myCustomFont';
font-weight: bold;
```

This picks `myCustomFont-Bold` on iOS but for android it picks a default font since it cannot find the font.  I have to say this on Android:

```
font-family: 'myCustomFont-Bold';
```

Hoping there is a way so we can use the font across platforms without having to change the font-family for bold or italic, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that stumbles on to here.  This is the way to do it: https://github.com/jsamr/react-native-font-demo

This other approach gets you most of the way there but not quite as good as the previous response: [How can i use same custom fonts for both android and ios using react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610282/how-can-i-use-same-custom-fonts-for-both-android-and-ios-using-react-native)